# UITableViewCell transparent background (including imageView/accessoryView)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

When I set the UITableViewCells `backgroundColor` to a semi-transparent color, it looks good, but the color doesn't cover the entire cell.

The area around the `imageView` and `accessoryView` are coming up as `[UIColor clearColor]`...

[image]

I've tried explicitly setting the `cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor` and `cell.imageView.backgroundColor` to be the same color as the cell's `backgroundColor`, but it doesn't work.  It puts a tiny box around the icon, but doesn't expand to fill the left edge.  The right edge seems unaffected by this.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT** : Here is the raw table cell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.1 blue:.1 alpha:.4];
        cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ben and I figured this out today, here's the summary for the group in case this catches anybody else.

You have to set the cell background and `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor` every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, not just during the `alloc/init` phase (i.e. if the `tableView` has a dequeue cache miss).

So, the code becomes this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.opaque = NO;        
    }

    // All bgColor configuration moves here
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.1 blue:.1 alpha:.4];
    cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: actually I had to do 1 more thing.  The cell.textLabel.backgroundColor needed to be set *AFTER* the cell's background color.  I have NO idea why I need to do this, but now it's working.  Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into setting the background color of the cell's `contentView` and keeping the cell, accessory, and image views transparent?

Also, [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) might help show you some alternatives.

Comment: I was using that article for inspiration, but unfortunately he doesn't use transparent cells.

Setting the contentView background color had very strange effects.  I also tried setting contentView.opaque = NO, but still looked awful.